# Error pagination when filter to list by category ListView Django

Tags: django

I'm new with programming, my mentor only youtube, and when i got error, i search similar error in stackoverflow, but no luck now.
I have a problem with my code or maybe my logic. I don't have much experience or knowledge about call queryset for filtering correctly.

This my `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
     path('product/<int:page>', ProductListView.as_view(), name='allproducts'),
     path('<categories>/<int:page>', ProductCategoryListView.as_view(), 
     name='product_category'),
]
```

I have ProductListView with no error pagination.

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'product_list'
    template_name = 'product.html'
    model = Product
    paginate_by = 16

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
        context ['catlist'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

- when i filter by category, pagination doesn't work. filter by
  category work fine, but when paginate_by more than my product, page
  error

> Reverse for 'product_category' with arguments '('', 2)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[^/]+)/(?P[0-9]+)$']\

```
class ProductCategoryListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'product_list'
    template_name = 'product_list.html'
    model = Product
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.queryset = self.model.objects.filter(category__name=self.kwargs['categories'])
        return super().get_queryset()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductCategoryListView, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
        context ['catlist'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

This my `models.py`

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_lokasi)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, editable=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

This my template for `ProductCategoryListView`

```
<div class="...">
            <div class="...">
                <a href="{% url 'products:allproducts' 1%}"...>
                    All Products
                </a>
                {% for cat in catlist %}
                <a href="{% url 'products:product_category' cat.name 1 %}"...>
                    {{ cat.name }}
                </a>
                {% endfor %}
                        <!-- Product List -->
        <div class="row isotope-grid">
            {% for prods in product_list %}
            <div class="...">
                <div class="...">
                    <div class="...">
                        <img src="{{ prods.image.url }}" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
                        <a href="../{{ prods.slug }}" class="...">
                            Quick View
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="...">
                        <div class="...">
                            <a href="product-detail.html" class="...">
                                    {{ prods.name }}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <!-- Pagination -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                {% if is_paginated %}
                    <nav aria-label="productPage">
                        <ul class="pagination">
                        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" href="{% url 'products:product_category' category page_obj.previous_page_number %}">Previous</a>
                            </li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li class="page-item disabled">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Previous</a>
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% for page in paginator.page_range %}
                            {% if page is page_obj.number %}
                            <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
                                <span class="page-link" href="#">{{page}}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>
                            </li>
                            {% else %}
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" href="{% url 'products:product_category' category page %}">{{page}}</a>
                            </li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" href="{% url 'products:product_category' category page_obj.next_page_number %}">Next</a>
                            </li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li class="page-item disabled">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Next</a>
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
```

I guess error comes from here cause logic use different models.

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
            context = super(ProductCategoryListView, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
            context ['catlist'] = Category.objects.all()
            return context
```

## my template

```
{% for cat in catlist %}
    <a href="{% url 'products:product_category' cat.name 1 %}"...>
        {{ cat.name }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

- I use `Category.objects.all()` because i don't know how to List
  Category from product, just for a name of category can be access.

I hope you guys understand what i asking about.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Exactly where is your problem ?

Comment: Your ```ListView``` will do pagination for ```Product``` model and not for ```Category```.

Comment: ya i guess.. but what do u think?

Comment: Write ```ListView``` for ```Category``` class,,, or implement custom ```Pagination``` and pass it to ```context``` from ```get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)```. See Paginator documentation in django docs. it's so easy to use.

Comment: You have problem in ```reverse``` method also, you are passing wrong arguments (with wrong data maybe). Just check they carefuly.

Comment: `self.queryset = self.model.objects.filter(category__name=self.kwargs['categories'])`  
is that call rawqueryset?
filter from product relation to category.. like this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/56387377/11591504..

Comment: It returns ```QuerySet``` and not ```RawQuerySet```. Technically it returns ```Product``` Model as a result, but will be filtered after ```SQL JOIN``` to ```Category``` Model.

Comment: ```self.model``` is ```Product``` in your case. ```self.model is Product # returns True```.

Comment: i confused.. i'll show you my project on github public. now i watching youtube tutorial how to upload project to github. thanks trying to help me.